# Left Outer Join Entity Framework getting error Unable to create a null constant

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to perform a left outer join. It seems to work fine, but I am having a problem when my Friends table is null.

For instance Users table has foreign key (friendId) that relates to the Table Friends (id) column.

Sometimes though my User won't link with a friend so I get this error:
Unable to create a null constant value of type 'PandaBrew.Models.FriendModel'

How do I deal with that?

Repo Code:

```
var authUser = (from u in db.Users
                        join f in db.Friends on u.FriendId equals f.Id into jointable
                        from j in jointable.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where u.EmailAddress == user.EmailAddress
                        select new UserModel
                        {
                            Id = u.Id,
                            CreatedOn = u.CreatedOn,
                            EmailAddress = u.EmailAddress,
                            FriendId = u.FriendId,
                            RoleId = u.RoleId,
                            PasswordHash = u.PasswordHash,
                            Friend = u.FriendId != null ? new FriendModel()
                                    {
                                        Alias = j.Alias,
                                        CarrierId = j.Id,
                                        CreatedOn = j.CreatedOn,
                                        FirstName = j.FirstName,
                                        Id = j.Id,
                                        LastName = j.LastName,
                                        Locked = j.Locked,
                                        PhoneNumber = j.PhoneNumber,
                                        SteamId = j.SteamId,
                                    } :  null,
                        }).SingleOrDefault();
```

I tried setting Friend to null when there is no friendId but it isn't working.

Comment: I usually work around this problem by creating an empty (in this case) FriendModel instead of null and then checking for that (and possibly setting Friend to null afterward). It's not a problem with your code, it's a problem with EF.

Comment: hmm can you show me what you mean? because when I set it empty i get a error still.

Comment: In it's simpelest form I mean: .. Friend = u.FriendId != null ? new FriendModel() { ... } : new FriendModel(), ... and then afterwards do something like "if (authUser.Friend.Id == 0) authUser.Friend = null".

Comment: I a new error: type FriendModel appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: Oh darn, I think I confused a couple of different workarounds I've used (don't have my projects or visual studio available at the moment so can't double check). But I think the other option is to do the "u.FriendId != null"-check for each property. Like so: ... Friend = new FriendModel() { Alias = u.FriendId != null ? j.Alias : "", ... }. I'll double-check when I get into work tomorrow if you don't have an answer to this question by then.

Comment: Awesome I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some digging in source control and memory I recalled that my initial comment was the first thing I tried that didn't end up working. In the end I settled on just splitting the query (removing the join) and checking afterwards if I needed a second one to get the related data. I first selected everything to an anonymous type and then filled my actual class as needed, but looking at it again I think there's a slightly easier cleaner way in your case (see below).

```
var authData = (from u in db.Users
                where u.EmailAddress == user.EmailAddress
                select new
                {
                    Id = u.Id,
                    CreatedOn = u.CreatedOn,
                    EmailAddress = u.EmailAddress,
                    FriendId = u.FriendId,
                    RoleId = u.RoleId,
                    PasswordHash = u.PasswordHash,
                    FriendId = u.FriendId
                }).SingleOrDefault();

var authUser = new UserModel()
{
    Id = authData.Id,
    CreatedOn = authData.CreatedOn,
    EmailAddress = authData.EmailAddress,
    FriendId = authData.FriendId,
    RoleId = authData.RoleId,
    PasswordHash = authData.PasswordHash
};

if (authData.FriendId != null)
{
    // Set authUser.Friend here with a new query
}
```

Or a cleaner way that should work is to initialize the Friend with just the ID:

```
var authUser = (from u in db.Users
                where u.EmailAddress == user.EmailAddress
                select new UserModel
                {
                    Id = u.Id,
                    CreatedOn = u.CreatedOn,
                    EmailAddress = u.EmailAddress,
                    FriendId = u.FriendId,
                    RoleId = u.RoleId,
                    PasswordHash = u.PasswordHash,
                    Friend = new FriendModel()
                            {
                                Id = u.FriendId ?? 0
                            },
                }).SingleOrDefault();

if (authUser.Friend.Id > 0)
{
    // Set authUser.Friend here with a new query
}
```